# Strange CandlestickChart EventLabels Behavior When Using Modified Data

Tags: options, charts

**Edit**: In attempting to showcase a simplified version of the issue, it seems instead I showcased a syntax error and didn't capture the correct issue.

The code below showcases the issue:

```
data2={{3868905600,{1.86,2.04,1.85,2.01}},{3868992000,{2.04, 2.11, 2.00, 2.05}},{3869078400,{ 1.99, 2.10, 1.80, 1.95}},{3869164800,{ 1.97, 1.97, 1.76, 1.83}},{3869251200,{ 1.83, 1.87, 1.78, 1.80}},{3869337600,{ 1.80, 1.85, 1.72, 1.82}},{3869424000,{ 1.82, 1.87, 1.75, 1.83}},{3869510400,{ 1.83, 1.87, 1.75, 1.84}},{3869596800,{ 1.84, 1.88, 1.76, 1.84}},{3869683200,{ 1.84, 1.89, 1.77, 1.85}}}

CandlestickChart[data2, EventLabels -> {Yesterday -> "\[UpArrow]"}]
```

[image]

In this case, the EventLabel should put an arrow on the 11th. The value for Yesterday is:

```
Yesterday // AbsoluteTime
```

[image]

The value for Yesterday is the 4th input in the list. It is not clear why the EventLabel is not showing up to label the 4th value.

Comment: You have a syntax mistake in your second example. It should be ``{Yesterday -> "\[UpArrow]"}`` not ``{Yesterday, "\[UpArrow]"}`` (comma vs. arrow). If you fix this, it works as expected :-)

Comment: To your edit: Which version are you using? It [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hPcr.png) for me in both 12.3 and 13.0 (Windows).

Comment: I'm using version 13.1 on Mac.

Comment: `$ 1.86` is not a numerical value. Use `Quantity[1.86, "USDollars"]` instead.

Comment: The $ 1.86 is a result of copying it into StackExchange. I'll edit that so it is easier to copy and replicate the issue.

Comment: With the corrected data I can reproduce the issue on "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)". Changed `Yesterday` to `{2022, 8, 11}` since the former will soon no longer be in the date range.